# Delphi double-side printer

Tags: delphi, printing

I have a PVC card printer which is able to print on both sides of a card at the same time.

the cards are 8.4mm X 5.4mm.

the printer is a Nisca PR5350.
http://www.teamnisca.com/products/5350/

I have the following code. the problem is that although I select "double-side" in the printer setting dialog, the printer prints each of the pages on separate cards.

I searched a bit in the internet and found that I have to set the printer mode to full-duplex in my code. but I don't know how to do it exactly.

this is my code...

```
with PrintDialog1 do
  // after the dialog executes, I open printer settings and select "double-side"
  if Execute then
    begin

      with printer do
        begin
          BeginDoc;
          // Here I draw the front of the card on printer canvas 
          NewPage;
          // After creating a new page, here I draw the back of the card on 
          // printer canvas.
          EndDoc;
        end;

    end;
```

Thank you.

Comment: See `TPrinterSetupDialog`. Drop it on a form and double click it. You can use it's properties - make sure to check those under *Advanced* if need be to find the setting you need. You use `Execute` to display it at runtime, just like `TPrintDialog`. The alternative is to use the WinAPI, retrieve the printer mode with `GetPrinter`, make the changes there by modifying that printer mode, and then updating with `SetPrinter`.

Comment: Oh, and what you're wanting to do (double-sided printing) is properly called `duplex printing`, and the property setting you're looking for in the dialog is `Duplex`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ken. I found a code which enables the Duplex printing feature of a printer. http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/showcode.php?id=1961

now the problem is that although both sides of the card have colors and a high quality, the printer prints the back side (which is the second page) in black and white and a very low quality. something like a monochrome bitmap.
the front page is printed fine.

Comment: When exactly do yopu call the code above? Before BeginDoc?

Comment: @adlabac this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514198/delphi-duplex-printing

Comment: Try using `GlobalUnlock` before BeginDoc.