# Delphi duplex printing

Tags: delphi, printing

I have a PVC card printer which prints on both sides of a card at the same time.
take a look at this question: [Delphi double-side printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382356/delphi-double-side-printer)

I managed to enable the duplex printing mode of the printer. now the problem is that the first page which is the front side of the card is printed fine but the back side which is the second page is printed in black and white and a very low quality. something like a monochrome bitmap.

this is the output of my program which is printed using MS XPS document printer.
as you can see there is no problem here, but when I select the PVC printer, I have problems in printing the back side.

Left page is the front side of the card which is printed fine but the right page is the back side of the card and is printed in black and white and a very low quality.

[image: Left page is the front side which is printed fine.]

```
var
  i, j: integer;
  ppix,ppiy,mmx,mmy: integer;
  XForm: TXForm;
  Device, Driver, Port: array[0..80] of Char;
  DevMode: THandle;
  pDevmode: PDeviceMode;
  insert_comm: wideString;
begin
  with PrintDialog1 do
if Execute then
  begin

    with printer do
      begin

        GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DevMode);
        if Devmode <> 0 then begin
           // lock it to get pointer to DEVMODE record
          pDevMode := GlobalLock(Devmode);
        if pDevmode <> nil then
          try
            with pDevmode^ do begin
              dmDuplex := DMDUP_VERTICAL;
              dmFields := dmFields or DM_DUPLEX;
            end;

            BeginDoc;

            ppix:=GetDeviceCaps(Handle,LOGPIXELSX);
            ppiy:=GetDeviceCaps(Handle,LOGPIXELSY);
            mmx:=round(ppix/25.4);
            mmy:=round(ppiy/25.4);

            SetGraphicsMode(Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
            XForm.eM11 := Cos(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM12 := Sin(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM21 := -Sin(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM22 := Cos(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eDx := (PageWidth div 2) - ((54 * mmy) div 2);
            XForm.eDy := 85 * mmx;
            SetWorldTransform(Canvas.Handle, XForm);


            // Here I draw the front side of the Card


            // New page for back side
            NewPage;

            SetGraphicsMode(Canvas.Handle, GM_ADVANCED);
            XForm.eM11 := Cos(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM12 := -Sin(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM21 := Sin(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eM22 := Cos(DegToRad(270));
            XForm.eDx := (PageHeight div 2);
            XForm.eDy := 0;
            SetWorldTransform(Canvas.Handle, XForm);


            // Here I draw the back side of the Card

            EndDoc;

            try
              bmp.Destroy;
            except
            end;


          finally
            // unlock devmode handle.
            GlobalUnlock(Devmode);
          end;
        end; { If }


      end;
end;
```

Thank you.

Comment: While I don't realy understand your code I'm wondering does the world transformation for the second page has to be so different from the world transformation for the first page? I mean in first page you are using PageWidth in calculation of eDx but on second page you are using PageHeight. That doesen't seem logical to me.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I hope you understand. it's because I want the back side to be printed on the card after being rotated 180 degrees. in this case when you flip the actual card horizontally, the back side is in the same rotation as the front side and you don't have to rotate the card again.

and now if you look at the picture. it's obvious that the back side is rotated compared to the front side.

Comment: You are wrong about the back side. It is neither of lower quality nor black and white. The only different things are the orientation and the language. Or something is wrong with my eyes...

Comment: This is the preview from MS XPS Document writer. it's fine and there's no problem with it. but when I select the PVC printer, the backside is printed in black and white and in low quality.

Comment: Ok. Then I don't have a problem with my eyes, but mind reading.

Comment: @Agha Based on you picture it seems that the page isn't rotated 180 degrees but mirored. Or are you perhaps using right to left fonts on one side of the card?

Comment: @SilverWarior Did you noticed the language on the print? It is RightToLeft written ;)

Comment: Also are you sure that your PVC pinter supports colored printing on both sides? I don't think all of them support this. So can you make a doublesided colored print from another program using your PVC printer?

Comment: @SirRufo Internet Explorer doesen't show that picture in good enough quality for me to be sure so I decided to rather go and ask to be sure.

Comment: @SilverWarior I was not sure at once but after reading "Islamic ..." on the right card it was clear ;)

Comment: I see what may cause the problem to you, but you'll have to try first. Namely, you should `GlobalUnlock` immediatelly after you finish changing the settings - before `BeginDoc`.